# Pass data from View Controller to View

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I have main View Controller, where are located application's data. This data, I need to send to the view, which contains UIView and nested to him UITableView. That UITableView is responsible for show pop up menu with part of my data in cells (specifically title of the theme).

[Interface of pop up menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT8TL.jpg)

I have tried to do this by protocol and delegate, but it was not successful. Maybe I did something wrong or it in general impossible and I need to find another way out?

**Data to pass**

```
    fileprivate var themes = [
    Theme(name: "Halloween",
          emoji: ["", "", "", "☠️", "", "", "⚰️", "", "", "", "⚱️", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
          backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
          buttonColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.5763723254, blue: 0, alpha: 1)),
    Theme(name: "Sports",
          emoji: ["", "⚽️", "", "", "", "‍♂️", "‍♀️", "⛳️", "", "", "", "⛸", "", "", "", "", "‍♂️", "‍♂️"],
          backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
          buttonColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1)),
    Theme(name: "Flags",
          emoji: ["", "", "", "️‍", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
          backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 1),
          buttonColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)),
    Theme(name: "Animals",
          emoji: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
          backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.3098039329, green: 0.2039215714, blue: 0.03921568766, alpha: 1),
          buttonColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1)),
    Theme(name: "Food",
          emoji: ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
          backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.1294117719, green: 0.2156862766, blue: 0.06666667014, alpha: 1),
          buttonColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644, green: 0.8862745166, blue: 0.5921568871, alpha: 1)),
    Theme(name: "Gadgets",
          emoji: ["⌚️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "⏰", "", "", "⏲", "⌨️", ""],
          backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1),
          buttonColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1))
]
```

**Class for the View**

```
class DropDownView: UIView {

fileprivate var listOfThemes = ["1", "2", "3"] //test data

fileprivate struct Keys {

    static let cellIdentifier = "cell"

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

} }

extension DropDownView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

fileprivate func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return listOfThemes.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Keys.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = listOfThemes[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

} }
```

Comment: Vlad, how do you initalize this view from your main ViewController?

Comment: fileprivate var dropDownView = DropDownView()

Comment: You might want to restructure your DropDownView to accept a list of themes in it's init method.

Comment: Or at least provide some way to set the `DropDownView`'s list of themes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving this but for this case the following seems simple and easy to achieve:

In your `DropDownView` class, declare `listOfThemes` array as following:

```
var listOfThemes: [Theme]!
```

Then in your mainVC when you initialize DropDownView, do the following before displaying the view:

```
fileprivate var dropDownView = DropDownView()
dropDownView.listOfThemes = themes // themes are the themes from your main VC
// now present it.
```